# what is the difference in vb.net web apps and c# .net webapps

Tags: c#, vb.net

can any one tell me the difference between vb.net web apps and c# .net webapps y most of the apps are done in c# rather than vb.net

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference, they all compile down to the same CLR.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing but preference. C# and VB.Net are extremely similar in nature as far as programming languages go.

Microsoft has said that both languages will co-evolve from now on.  They will both get the same additional features with each new release, and MS is committed to both.  There was a rumor that VB was going to be replaced by C#, but that is not true.  They have dispelled that myth.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are more coders that use c#, perhaps?  Underlying philosophy of .net is that you can use language that you are most comfortable with, and stay in the same environment.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the language that the code behind files are written in.

Both use the same objects and .NET framework, it's only a choice of programming language.

As for why most examples are in C#, more people prefer to use that.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've heard, VB.NET was shoehorned into .NET as a late addition because too many programmers were familiar with it. Programmers tend to have their preferences with higher-level languages (which is by far the most distinct difference). In the end, they both provide virtually the same capability and functionality.

Comment: right for the shoehorn one, however I disagree on being the same, even if the use the same runtime their compiler are vastly different, and the IL code is also very different

Comment: @dvhh, fair enough -- I've removed my reference to them being technically identical.

Comment: @dvhh this is a misnomer.  C# and VB on .NET controls compile to the same CLR, if you write a custom control, then it might be difficult to make them look the same, but it can still be done.

Comment: VB.NET got some extra dependencies to mimic some default VB functions on the global module for example. And I'm pretty sure that running through a decompiler even the most simple code would produce different results.

Comment: @dvhh You might be interested to see that JaredPar, who used to work on the VB.Net compiler, [says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836073/is-c-faster-than-vb-net/3836199#3836199) that for most features it outputs exactly the same IL as the C# compiler.

Comment: @MarkJ so the keyword here is *MOST*, I kinda agree that they are kinda the same on an atomic level, but you've agree that for the syntaxic sugar their is some code overhead added, which hopefully is mostly removed at JIT compile time.