# Is there any major difference when we compare the efficiency of VB.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

For example, when the codes are compiled, will VB.NET tend to be slower than C#? Or are there any major features in VB.NET / C# that we cannot find in the other language?

Comment: When code is compiled, instructions generated are the same. So, IMO, execution speed is the same.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006927/which-one-is-faster-c-sharp-or-vb-net ?

Comment: @Marco - It depends. **Are** the instructions generated the same?

Comment: @Oded subtle approach ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is C# faster than VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836073/is-c-sharp-faster-than-vb-net)

Comment: @Oded: I'd like to think that using classes "shared" between two languages, they generate same IL. But your point is right... in C# and VB you can use different patterns/logic, so compiler could produce different IL. Anyway if you write "same" code, I suppose we can expect same speed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when the codes are compiled, will VB.NET tend to be slower than C#?

[Reference -](http://dng-dotnetframework.blogspot.com/2007/05/what-is-msil-microsoft-intermediate.html) 
An intermediate language generated by compiler is called MSIL. All .Net assemblies are represented in MSIL. The main Advantage of using MSIL is it provides equal performance for multiple language programming, as code is compiled to native code.

Example: Performance of application developed in C# is similar to VB.net or any other .Net compliant language that is because of MSIL.

Comment: So, if you can assert that the IL produced by a bit of VB.NET is identical to that produced by a bit of C#, then they will run identically.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/vbnet-vs-c-round-2-pounding-on-performance/1027686

Comment: +1 Oded because the IL generated by VB is often similar to that generated by C#, but not always identical. For instance the two languages support different features: unsafe code, exception filters, etc.