# Physics Library for VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, physics-engine

Hi is there any library which can interact with vb.net. I searched a little bit but I just found libraries for c#. I know it's not suitable to use vb.net for making these stuffs but I wanted to know.

Thanks.

Comment: VB.Net is perfectly suitable for this stuff, why wouldn't it be? Also, .net libraries are language agnostic, it doesn't matter if a library was built with C#, you can use it in VB.Net.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - Almost right. The library will need to be CLS compliant.

Comment: @Oded: Touché. The _CLS Compliant_ in my comment was obviously silent, like the _b_ in lamb :)

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - I don't know, some people say that It's too managed or too slow.

Comment: See [Is C# code faster than Visual Basic.NET code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223660/is-c-code-faster-than-visual-basic-net-code), there is no real difference. C# may win for somethings, VB may win for others but the differences really are - mostly - negligable . . . and if differences on that scale worry you, then you shouldn't be using a mananaged language, and should be using something where you can fine tune memory allocations (such as C++).

Comment: I'm programming with C++ 3 years and visual basic lang for 6 years but C++ is time expensive and VB is not able to perform some of my aims. I'm working on a game engine with VB.Net, not exactly engine cuz it's in the first of way, and I want to see If it's able to work for game engine or not. I think it's able but I'm now working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A .NET library can be used by any .NET language, so long as it is [CLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Specification) compliant.

I expect a physics library to be CLS compliant.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It means every library even written in c# can be implemented in vb.net. Cool. I'm gonna try it. But I was thinking about converting them to VB.Net.

Comment: @MahanGM - It means that once compiled, the assembly can be _used_ by any other .NET language.

Comment: Using Redgates refelector or ILSpy (ILSpy is free) you can open any .net dll, written in any language, and see what the code would look like in VB.Net or C#.